# c# express back up/restore database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, backup, restore

I am completely lost here and I am running out of time. Let me explain my situation:

I have created a software in C# express 2010 and SQL Server Express 2008 R2.

Now in the settings section of my software, the user is supposed to be able to make manual back ups/restores of the database.

Also he is supposed to be able to schedule back ups of the database, which will run at time that he will set.

I do not have a clue on how to get both of these working and I am hoping that someone here may point me in the correct direction.

- I need to be able to create a
  backup/restore of the database from
  the click of a button
- I need to be able to schedule backup
  processes

Please keep in mind that when the user will install the software on his computer, he will not have sql server installed (I am saying this because I am under the impression that SMO requires sql server to be pre installed on the client machine).

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477355/backup-sql-server-database-from-windows-form-application-by-a-button-click

The above link explains how to restore and backup in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at this C# example for using SMO to backup the database

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/95750bdf-fcb1-45bf-9247-d7c0e1b9c8d2/

The other option is to run a process and call sqlcmd from code

http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=27

Here is some sample code to execute process

```
string fileName = @"C:\Backup.sql";

ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("sqlcmd", @" -S .\SQLExpress -U sa -d mydatabasename -o C:\sqlout.txt -i """ + @fileName + @""" -P");

 info.UseShellExecute = false;

 info.CreateNoWindow = true;

 info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

 info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

 Process p = new Process();

 p.StartInfo = info;

 p.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this in more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try [Google](http://www.google.com/).

1. [Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)
2. [Restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
3. [Automate backup scripts](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic609746-357-1.aspx#bm1006902) using the [SQL Job Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739.aspx)

I'm assuming you can create Windows Forms and wire up `OnClick` events, and run `SqlCommand`'s against the database.  Then it's just a matter of using the documentation above to  write the appropriate queries when the user presses the appropriate button.

BTW: This is a Q&A site, not an emergency consultant shop.  Don't say things like "I'm running out of time" and don't write up large lists of requirements and say tell me how to do this.  You'll get absolutely no help  that way. Ask **specific** questions after demonstrating your effort and specific technical problem.

Comment: Imagine how profitable an emergency consultant shop that's just like StackOverflow would be. (Although experts exchange tried that and failed.)